# ActiveClassName in NavLink requires page-reload to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want to add some style to my menu's upon being active.
The active style only displays after reloading the page.

```
        <Menu.Item className="law" header as={NavLink} exact to="/law" activeClassName="test">  
                </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item className="revision" header as={NavLink} exact to="/revisions" activeClassName="test">
               </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item className="changes" header as={NavLink} exact to="/changes" activeClassName="test">
               </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item className="settings" header as={NavLink} exact to="/settings" activeClassName="test">
             </Menu.Item>
```

Any suggestions on how i can make the ActiveClassName trigger without a page-reload?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of that can possibly be the problem here, is that the ReactRouter `NavLink` component does like that you used `<Menu.Item />` instead of the normal `<NavLink />` component

Comment: I'am dependent on the <Menu.Item/>. There has to be a way to solve this including both?